# jQuery Errors / Page Hangs in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

jQuery is causing my pages to hang in IE8 and also seems to be causing some other errors.

The page in question is:

http://www.yogahunter.com/

- It hangs while loading in IE8. I am getting the error:

> document.body is null or not an object jquery-1.3.2.min.js, line 19 character 23004

I am pretty sure that it is the jQuery because if I delete the call to jQuery, the page loads quickly. But once I put the call to jQuery back in, it hangs on load.

- Also, when I am navigating away from certain pages, I get another error (which I think is related to google maps). The error is:

> Object expected awareness-center-11.htm, line 38 character 1

You will see this error go to:

http://www.yogahunter.com/detail/awareness-center-11.htm

and then navigate to a different page on the site.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It helps if you include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: thanks so much, jrummell: Unfortunately i have to wait atwo more hourse because the stackoverflow system only lets me post a reply once every 8 hours, and the code is too big to post in these comment sections. But I think the problem might be as rlemon pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild leap and say that version 1.3.2 of jQuery and version 1.7.2 of jQuery UI are not compatible??

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/ajaxupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi there, rlemon:

thanks for the response.

Again, since I am a noob, can I ask if you are being serious or sarcastic? and please don't take offense at me asking :)

I really have no idea whether they are compatible or not, but if you think this is a possible reason, then I will try to look into it.

Thanks again for taking the time to look at the site and thanks in advance for any clarification you might be able to provide. I feel pretty lost with all this.

Comment: I don't think that there is A CONFLICT between the two different versions of jquery because I commented out the second call ( the <script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script> ) and left the call to the jquery-1.3.2.min.js in place, and it still hangs. Then I did the opposite: I commented out the call to the jquery-1.3.2.min.js and left the jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js in place and it DIDN'T hang. So I think the problem is with the jquery-1.3.2.min.js. But how do I check that now? Maybe it is conflicting with something else?

Comment: Ok, it looks like the conflict is between jquery-1.3.2.min.js and jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js, because if I don't load EITHER one fo the two, then the page loads without hanging. But if I load BOTH then the page hangs. Any suggestion on where to go from here?